# A query is not returning results using php that works using straight SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**UPDATE:** - 
So I have found that the cause of the problem is that I am running a previous query (in this case a multi_query) that appears to be out of sync with the next query.  If I close and reopen the connection, it works fine, but there is probably a better way to go about solving this problem.  Any pointers on a better way are appreciated.

Complete code:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['survey']['contact']['contactEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $survey = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $survey = $survey['survey'];
    $email = $survey['contact']['contactEmail'];
    include 'databaseconnection.php';
    /*
     * This part works...
     */
    $query = "BEGIN;INSERT INTO interests(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO equipment(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email'); INSERT INTO classes(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO housing(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO newSkills(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO selfIdentity(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO areYouA(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO locationIdeas(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO involved(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');INSERT INTO contact(contactEmail) VALUES ('$email');";
    foreach ($survey as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            $query.= "UPDATE $key SET $key.$k = '$v' WHERE $key.contactEmail='$email';";
        }
    }

    $query.="COMMIT;";
    if (!($mysqli->multi_query($query))) {
        echo "Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    /*
     * This subsequent query does not work unless I close the connection and restart it, giving an " Error: (2014) Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now "
     */
/*******************************************/
    $mysqli->close();
    include 'databaseconnection.php';
/*******************************************/

    $query = "SELECT distinct * FROM interests, equipment, classes, housing, newSkills, selfIdentity, areYouA, locationIdeas, involved, contact WHERE interests.contactEmail='$email' AND equipment.contactEmail='$email' AND classes.contactEmail='$email' AND housing.contactEmail='$email' AND newSkills.contactEmail='$email' AND selfIdentity.contactEmail='$email' AND areYouA.contactEmail='$email' AND locationIdeas.contactEmail='$email' AND involved.contactEmail='$email' AND contact.contactEmail='$email';";
    if (!($result = $mysqli->query($query))) {
        echo "Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    $statistics = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    var_dump($statistics);
} else {
    echo 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
```

I am baffled as to why this query is not returning any results.  The code is supposed to be returning someone's entry in a survey for confirmation that it was received and the '$email' is the email address of the person who did the survey.  But it appears not to be returning anything (nothing is returned from a var_dump of the $result variable) and I get the following message"

The relevant code:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT distinct * FROM interests, equipment, classes, housing, newSkills, selfIdentity, areYouA, locationIdeas, involved, contact WHERE interests.contactEmail='$email' AND equipment.contactEmail='$email' AND classes.contactEmail='$email' AND housing.contactEmail='$email' AND newSkills.contactEmail='$email' AND selfIdentity.contactEmail='$email' AND areYouA.contactEmail='$email' AND locationIdeas.contactEmail='$email' AND involved.contactEmail='$email' AND contact.contactEmail='$email';");
var_dump($result);
$statistics = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($statistics as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . ' : ' . $v;
}
```

The Error Message:
**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\otherrealmhomepageredesign\serversidestuff\SurveySubmission.php** on line **41**

When I do a dummy search for a test email using straight sql in MySQL Workbench, I get the results I am looking for.

Straight SQL:

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM interests, equipment, classes, housing, newSkills, selfIdentity, areYouA, locationIdeas, involved, contact 
WHERE interests.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND equipment.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND classes.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND housing.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND newSkills.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND 
selfIdentity.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND areYouA.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND locationIdeas.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND involved.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT' AND contact.contactEmail='bob@t.qdTT';
```

Results:

```
'bob@t.qdTT', NULL, NULL, 'on', 'on', NULL, NULL, 'dbf gbcvb', 'bob@t.qdTT', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'on', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'on', 'dfxbv ', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'on', NULL, NULL, 'on', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'erdgettrf', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'yes', 'rtfhthtrfgh', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'no', 'ehfnsrtehtertdf', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'other', 'dherdgdfxbdfb', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'rhgergbdbgdfbdf', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'sfgdregbegerg', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'no', 'aegsdgdr', 'estgdfbdfxbdfx ', 'bob@t.qdTT', 'Asghd', '378767'
```

Comment: "DISTINCT *" seems a bit of nonsense :-( And please don't use implicit join syntax

Comment: its easier to debug if you gassing the query to a variable, then you can echo it and check it

Comment: As an aside, make sure those variables in the query are not from user input, or are escaped if they are. It would be much better to use parameterisation, in case you have a SQL injection vulnerability here.

Comment: I expect `$result` is null, which would point to a problem with the database. Maybe you are not connected? If you retrieve the error from the database you'll find out what the problem is.

Comment: Of course $result is null - that is the problem :-).  And there is not a problem with the database connection because I am able to insert and update (this is the first step in the survey submission process, then I want results to be returned).  It is probably an issue with how php interprets the query as opposed to how native a MySQL does it.  I will read up more on this method and try another approach, but if anyone knows what the problem is and could enlighten me, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known feature / bug with mysqli. You have to free all the results from the queries you've done so far before you can make more.

After this...

```
if (!($mysqli->multi_query($query))) {
    echo "Error: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Try...

```
while($mysqli->more_results())
{
    $mysqli->next_result();
    $discard = $mysqli->store_result();
}
```

While `INSERT` and `UPDATE` don't return result sets, they do return statuses that will be considered results to `mysqli`